# How can I connect the H1 ZOOM USB microphone to use it on Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, webcam, microphone

I have a H1 Zoom Recorder and it functions as a USB Mic. I connect it to Ubuntu 16.04, but I am unable to find it under 'Input' tab of the 'Sounds' option.

I went on to Install pauvcontrol but I do not find the option there. I can confirm that the device (Zoom Recorder) is working well.

My intention is to use the Mic with Cheese Webcam Booth and with Audacity eventually.

As advised I am leaving the following details:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.  Bus 001 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 003 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 002 Device 005: ID
04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd  Bus 002 Device 006: ID
04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth Bus 002
Device 003: ID 06cb:7406 Synaptics, Inc.  Bus 002 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


$ pactl list sources
Source #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xd1610000 irq 34"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0c0c"
        device.product.name = "Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #1
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 7
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1614000 irq 33"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8c20"
        device.product.name = "8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "1"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #2
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 7
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 7436 /  11% / -56.71 dB,   front-right: 7436 /  11% / -56.71 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 5206 /   8% / -66.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC283 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC283 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1614000 irq 33"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8c20"
        device.product.name = "8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC283"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0283,10250920,00100003"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority: 8700)
    Active Port: analog-input-mic
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Setting up the H1 ZOOM as a usb microphone

Coincidentally, I own an H1, and this is how to make it available as a usb microphone:

---

The trick is in the moment that you connect the microphone:

- With the H1 switched off, connect it to your computer.
- Look at the small screen on the micro, it flashes, switching between <kbd>Audio</kbd> and <kbd>USB</kbd>. Push the record button while <kbd>Audio</kbd> is on. Subsequently confirm the bitrate and you are done.

Now it should be available in sound settings as `H4`:

[image]

#### If it doesn't work

- According to [this website](https://gnomecoder.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/zoom-h1-firmware-update-2-0-adds-usb-digital-audio-support-in-linux/), you need a recent version of the firmware to use it on Linux. The official download link has changed though, download [here](https://www.zoom.co.jp/products/handy-recorder/h1-handy-recorder#downloads).
- The steps to update, according to manual:

  [image]

The full manual can be downloaded [here](https://www.zoom.co.jp/sites/default/files/products/downloads/pdfs/E_H1.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Jacob, but as mentioned, I do not see an option in the Input or the Output tabs.

Comment: the version displayed on the boot up screen is 21 10, which I believe is the latest. Hence I do not think that the version is the problem. Also, the ports are functioning well.  I will now try on someone's mac and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the working solution was to change a cable I used. With another cable everything worked perfectly

Comment: Remarkably, this was the case for me as well, but I had to go through *4* cables, ALL of which worked on other devices, before I found one that worked on my H1n. So if you're the kind of person who normally thinks "yea, I know, they always tell this to the non-tech-savvy people to make sure they're using a cable that isn't actually broken," give it a shot, because the H1n seems to be particularly picky.

Answer (score 0):

Followed advice here,still couldnt get it to work with audacity.

Zoom doesnt appear in input device list of Audacity.

i was able to fix it by

1. start recording in audacity using any other available device
2. run pavucontrol
3. go to 'Recording' tab
4. change the input device for audacity to 'H4 Digital Recorder' via dropdown list.